# Local Notifications at a specific time

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I have an app and I need to have the notifications at a specific date and time. I am using the following code to set the date and time.

```
let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()

let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Sound], categories: nil)
app.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

let date = NSDateComponents()
date.hour = 5
date.minute = 0
date.month = 5
date.day = 21
date.year = 2016
date.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()

let alarm = UILocalNotification()
alarm.fireDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(date)
alarm.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
alarm.alertTitle = ""
alarm.alertBody = ""
alarm.soundName = "Sound.wav"
app.scheduleLocalNotification(alarm)
```

I have allowed notifications and I can schedule ten seconds after the user leaves the app but not for a specific time.

Comment: The date in your sample code is in the past (5am today).

Comment: So notifications use military time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code is correct except for one thing, the hour. NSDate works on 24-hour system. So if you want the notification to come on 5 PM you need to set the hour value to 17

```
date.hour = 5 //this means 05:00 AM
date.minute = 0

date.hour = 17 //this mean 05:00 PM
date.minute = 0
```

P.S. - Your `alertBody` and `alertTitle` are blank. You might want to set it to something so that it shows up.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score -1):

Set your Date as below

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = /*find out and place date format from http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime*/
let customDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(/*your_date_string*/)

// your code
 alarm.fireDate = customDate
```

your_date_string will be the date&time when you want to schedule the notification.

Hope this Helps!