# How do I send local notifications at a specific time in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilocalnotification

I have been looking all over for an answer on how to send notifications at a specific time of day. I need it to display a local notification to the user's device every weekday at 8:00 A.M. I am aware that this question has been answered before. I found a Stack Overflow question: [Local Notifications at a specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367981/local-notifications-at-a-specific-time)

Unfortunately, it was pretty outdated as most of the code was removed from Swift since iOS 11 was released. I needed a more recent answer. I am kind of new to Swift programming. If someone could help me out and give me a more recent answer, that would be amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of what I have used for scheduling local notifications using Notification Centre.

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "My title"
content.body = "Lots of text"
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
content.categoryIdentifier = "yourIdentifier"
content.userInfo = ["example": "information"] // You can retrieve this when displaying notification

// Setup trigger time          
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone.current
let testDate = Date() + 5 // Set this to whatever date you need
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: testDate, repeats: false)

// Create request               
let uniqueID = UUID().uuidString // Keep a record of this if necessary
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uniqueID, content: content, trigger: trigger)
center.add(request) // Add the notification request
```

The `Date` object (represented by `testDate` above) can be whatever date you want. It is often convenient to create it from `DateComponents`.

You will need to ask permission for local notifications in the App Delegate at startup to allow this to work. Here is an example.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Ask permission for notifications
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            if granted {
                print("Permission granted")
            } else {
                print("Permission denied\n")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

This is an example of what I have used for scheduling local notifications using Notification Center.

```
import UserNotifications

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    //MARK: Authorization
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    
    
    //Delegate for UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    center.delegate = self
    
    //Permission for request alert, soud and badge
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
        // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
        if(!granted){
            print("not accept authorization")
        }else{
            print("accept authorization")
            
            center.delegate = self
            
            
        }
    }
    return true
}

}
```

**send notification**

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "We have a new message for you", arguments: nil)
        content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Open the app for see", arguments: nil)
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        content.badge = 1
        let identifier = id.uuidString

    //Receive notification after 5 sec
    //let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
    
    //Receive with date
    var dateInfo = DateComponents()
    dateInfo.day = day //Put your day
    dateInfo.month = month //Put your month
    dateInfo.year = year // Put your year
    dateInfo.hour = 8 //Put your hour
    dateInfo.minute = 0 //Put your minutes
    
    //specify if repeats or no
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateInfo, repeats: true)
    
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    print(identifier)
    center.add(request) { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }else{
            print("send!!")
        }
    }
```

**remembering to read this in the documentation:**

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH3-SW1